# Erro The user denied your request ao tentar gerar o Access Token do Instagram

Tags: instagram-api

Registrei a minha conta na área de desenvolvimento do Instagram para gerar o Access Token mas quando vou gerar ele acaba negando a requisição. Eu já realizei o mesmo processo em outras contas mas nessa conta eu não estou conseguindo gerar o token.

**URL usada para gerar o Access Token** https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=[MY_CLIENT_ID_HERE]&redirect_uri=http://localhost&response_type=token

Segue prints da configuração da conta

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: Erro apresentado depois de autorizar o aplicativo]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que a API do Instagram, que aparentemente será descontinuada, espera pela palava "Authorize" em vez de "Autorizar".

Tivemos o mesmo problema, e conseguimos resolver (gambiarra detected) adicionando o seguinte parâmetro na QueryString da URL usada para gerar o Access Token: &hl=en

Isso força o idioma inglês na tela de autorização, fazendo com que o botão vire "Authorize".

Espero ter ajudado.